# Why am I getting warning message: "Could not open directory 'public/img/dir-foe': Permission denied" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, git

The warning says,

> warning: could not open directory 'public/img/dir-foe': Permission denied
>
> On branch branch-bar

I tried using `chmod 777 -r` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What command are you running that generates this error?

Comment: Look at the permissions on this directory : from `bash` : `ls -ld public/img/dir-foe`, if you are running git-bash / Windows, look at the permissions from Windows. More particularly : look at the owner of this directory.

Comment: If you once ran a git action using `sudo` (or "run as asministrator" on windows), chances are some of your files are owned by `root`.

Comment: To fix this, change the owner : `sudo chown -R mysusername:myusergroup public/img/dir-foe` on linux, or right-click > Properties and fix ownershup on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /directory_path
```